# Default gateway in VPC with Public and Private Subnets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

Lets assume I have a VPC (`172.16.0.0/16`) with Public (`172.16.0.0/24`) and Private (`172.16.1.0/24`) subnets. Also I have one Internet Gateway (`172.16.0.1/24`) and one NAT Gateway (`172.16.1.x/24`). Note that the last bit is `x`, as IP address is assigned dynamically.

When I spawn an instances in the public subnet the `default gateway` is configured like so:

```
default via 172.16.0.1 dev eth0
```

When I spawn an instance in the private subnet I would like that instance had the `default gateway` configured like so:

```
default via 172.16.1.x dev eth0
```

Note: `x` in the last bit of the IP should match NAT-GW IP address.

At present I have to manually configure routing, thus change `default gateway` and add explicit route to other subnet:

```
default via 172.16.1.x dev eth0
172.16.0.0/24 via 172.16.1.1 dev eth0
```

Things like these should be possible to configure via `DHCP`, but `aws` `DHCP` seems to have a very limited set of settings.

***EDIT - Route Tables***:

Private subnet

```
172.16.0.0/16 local Active No
0.0.0.0/0 nat-id Active No
```

Public subnet

```
172.16.0.0/16 local Active No
0.0.0.0/0 igw-id Active No
```

Comment: Did you create your VPC manually or using the wizard in the dashboard?

Comment: I'm not sure how it was created, I'm just taking it over from someone else. What difference does it make anyway?

Comment: It makes a lot a difference. You wouldn't be asking questions like this.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that your routing table for the private subnets needs some attention and may need to be directed to a NAT instance to allow passage to the public internet. What do the route tables for your private subnets looks like?
This should help you out as well - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Scenario2.html

Thanks,
//P

Comment: Please see edited question. Your URL to docs - it was my entry point where I started and I believe I have everything configured according to that document.

Comment: Hmmm if you are inheriting... there are quite a few things that could be wrong here - If you are able to, it might be worth destroying and starting again using cloudformation - here are some templates to help you https://github.com/widdix/aws-cf-templates/tree/master/vpc
just run each json through Cloudformation to create the network you would like